# scenario background- launch wcf service

Tags: c#, specflow, topshelf

I'm testing a WCF service methods using specflow and nunit; my scenarios look like the following:

```
Feature: GetAccount
    Testing API method 'get account'

Background: 
    Given Server is running

Scenario: Succesful Get
    Given An Existing Account
    When I call the GetAccount API method With password = "123"
    Then the result should be Success
```

I'm not sure on how to implement the background step;
The server can be run as console / windows service using Topshelf-

```
private static void Main()
    {

      Host host = HostFactory.New(config =>
                                    {
                                      config.Service<ServiceInitializer>(service =>
                                                                      {
                                                                        service.ConstructUsing(s => new ServiceInitializer());
                                                                        service.WhenStarted((s, control) => s.Start(control));
                                                                        service.WhenStopped((s, control) => s.Stop(control));
                                                                      });
                                      config.RunAsPrompt();

                                    });
      host.Run();
    }


public class ServiceInitializer : ServiceControl

  {
    private readonly ILog m_log;

    public ServiceInitializer()
    {
      log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
      m_log = LogManager.GetLogger("Server");
    }


    public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
    {
      try
      {
        var host = new IoCServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

        host.Open();
        m_log.Info("Server is now open.");

        return true;
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
        m_log.Fatal("Initialization of service failed",exception);
        return false;
      }
    }


    public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl)
    {
      m_log.Info("Server has closed");
      return true;
    }

  }
```

should I just execute the .exe service file, or can I use my `ServiceInitializer` in some way?  perhaps I could use nUnit's `[SetUpFixture]`?
Are there any Specflow best practices?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider what you want to test.

- Do you need to test that Windows correctly runs services?
- Do you need to test that Topshelf correctly starts services?
- Or do you just want to test that GetAccount works?

I'll bet that you are using Topshelf to make your life easier, so do that and *trust* that their code works within windows. Its a valid assumption since there code will be used in many places and they probably have their own test suites, and if your assumption is wrong, then test it later when you find the problems.

So all you really need is

```
[BeforeFeature]
public void Background()
{
  FeatureContext.Current["Host"] =new MyHostObject();
}

[When("I call GetAccount API method with password =\"(\.*)\"")]
public void WhenICallGetAccount(string password)
{
  var host = (MyHostObject)FeatureContext.Current["Host"];
  ScenarioContext.Current["Account"] = host.GetAccount(password);
}

[Then("the result should be success")]
public void ThenTheResultShouldBeSuccessful()
{
  var account = (MyAccount)ScenarioContext.Current["Account"];
  //assuming using Should;
  account.ShouldNotBeNull();
}
```